# Traefik redirect frontend service doesn't work

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I have problem with my traefik configuration ...
I would like frontend redirect regex for https services but in my docker-compose the following configuration seems not working (and not appear on trafik GUI).
In log (debug level) nothing interesting.
My labels :

```
    - traefik.http.port=80
    - traefik.http.frontend.entryPoints=http
    - traefik.https.port=443
    - traefik.https.frontend.entryPoints=https
    - traefik.https.protocol=https
    - traefik.backend.loadbalancer.stickiness=true
    - traefik.frontend.rule=HostRegexp:{subdomain:[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+}.mydomain.com
    - traefik.https.frontend.redirect.permanent=true
    - traefik.https.frontend.redirect.regex=^https://(.*)/$$"
    - traefik.https.frontend.redirect.remplacement=https://$${1}/myapp/
```